# Where to get apache latest setup for windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, tomcat

i have downloaded many versions from the apache site, but no one has a setup thing, how do i install it?

There is this version apache-tomcat-6.0.32-windows-x86 that i downloaded from another site which has a tomcat6.exe file in the bin but its also not running.

Can anybody help me out to give me the exact link where i can download the installable version, please dont give me the page link, just give me the exact link, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at WAMP server if you are just getting started. It's an installable package that will do most of the configuration work for you. http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Here is the direct link http://www.wampserver.com/en/dl32.php